# Touchpad not Working Even after Grub Change

Tags: 20.04, grub2, touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new Acer Nitro AN17-71 alongside Windows 11. I had some problems during the install with my RTX 4060 graphics card, but I was able to resolve them by adding `nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0` to the grub menu. Then I was able to install Ubuntu, and after that install the 525.147.05 Nvidia Driver via `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`, which I need to run Isaac Sim.

My only problem now is the touchpad. It never worked (also not during the Ubuntu setup process). I tried adding `i8042.nomux i8042.noloop` to the grub, but it does not work. Running `xinput list` does not indicate a touchpad. I already checked if I can turn my touchpad on/off from the keyboard which does not seem to be the case. Additionally, I cannot find a touchpad option in the BIOS. An external USB Mouse works fine though. On Windows, the touchpad works fine too. What should I do?

I would really appreciate some help with my problem.
Cheers